# Simplifying $\frac{\sin\alpha\cos^2\beta}{\sin\beta}+\frac{\sin\beta\cos^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$

Tags: trigonometry

How to simplify the expression and get a closed form?

> $$\frac{\sin\alpha\cos^2\beta}{\sin\beta}+\frac{\sin\beta\cos^2\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$$
>   where $\alpha := \frac12(m+1)\theta$ and $\beta:=\frac12(m-1)\theta$; and where $m$ is an integer.

I wanna get rid of the denominators or make it a constant without $m$, but don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\frac{\sin\frac{m+1}{2}\theta\cos^2\frac{m-1}{2}\theta}{\sin\frac{m-1}{2}\theta}+\frac{\sin\frac{m-1}{2}\theta\cos^2\frac{m+1}{2}\theta}{\sin\frac{m+1}{2}\theta}&=\frac{\left( \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta \cos \frac{m-1}2\theta\right)^2+\left( \sin \frac{m-1}2\theta\cos\frac{m+1}2\theta\right)^2}{\sin \frac{m-1}2\theta \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta}\\
&=\frac{\left( \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta \cos \frac{m-1}2\theta\right)^2+\left( \sin \frac{m-1}2\theta\cos\frac{m+1}2\theta\right)^2}{\sin \frac{m-1}2\theta \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta}\\
&=\frac{\left( \sin m\theta +\sin \theta\right)^2+\left( \sin m\theta-\sin\theta\right)^2}{4\sin \frac{m-1}2\theta \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2 m\theta + \sin^2 \theta}{{2\sin \frac{m-1}2\theta \sin \frac{m+1}2\theta}} \\
&=\frac{\sin^2 m\theta + \sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta- \cos m\theta}
\end{align}

[image]

From this [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x5mwc3c1bu) link, the vertical asymptotes is a function of $m$. Hence $m$ is a term in the denominator.

The vertical asymptotes (which due to dision by $0$ in the denominator) appear where $\sin \left( \frac{m-1}2 \theta\right)=0$ or $\sin \left( \frac{m+1}2 \theta\right)=0$, that is when

$$\frac{m \pm 1}2 \theta = k\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

$$\theta = \frac{2k\pi}{m \pm 1} , k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

which is a function of $m$. The denominator is dependent on $m$.

Comment: Actually I started from your result, what I want is get rid of the denominator.

Comment: where did you get the question from? is it promised that it can be done? can we use $cosec$?

Comment: here is a [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x5mwc3c1bu) link for your graph, as you changes $m$, the graph changes.

Comment: Thank you. You can use $cosec$ only if there is no $m$ in it. I wanna the denominator with no $m$.

Comment: is it promised that it can be done? If I plot the graph correctly (please check), the vertical asymptotes seems to be a function of $m$.

Comment: Frankly I don't know, so I ask online if anyone knows a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

If we have $z=\exp(i\theta/2)$ then this is
\begin{align}
&\frac{(z^{m+1}-z^{-(m+1)})(z^{m-1}+z^{-(m-1)})^2}{4(z^{m-1}-z^{-(m-1)})}+\frac{(z^{m-1}-z^{-(m-1)})(z^{m+1}+z^{-(m+1)})^2}{4(z^{m+1}-z^{-(m+1)})}\\
&=\frac{(z^{m+1}-z^{-(m+1)})^2(z^{m-1}+z^{-(m-1)})^2+
(z^{m-1}-z^{-(m-1)})^2(z^{m+1}+z^{-(m+1)})^2}
{4(z^{m-1}-z^{-(m-1)})(z^{m+1}-z^{-(m+1)})}\\
&=\frac{(z^{2m}-z^2+z^{-2}-z^{-2m})^2+
(z^{2m}+z^2-z^{-2}-z^{-2m})^2}
{4(z^{2m}-z^2-z^{-2}+z^{-2m})}\\
&=\frac{(z^{2m}-z^{-2m})^2+(z^2-z^{-2})^2}
{2(z^{2m}-z^2-z^{-2}+z^{-2m})}\\
&=-\frac{\sin^2 m\theta+\sin^2\theta}{\cos m\theta-\cos \theta}.
\end{align}
I haven't got rid of the denominator, but it is an an alternative
(simpler?) form. One could cancel a $\sin\theta$ but that seems
to complicate things...

Comment: Actually I started from your final result, what I want is get rid of the denominator or make it a constant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can get rid of the denominator, but you can try to use [these identities.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities)

Answer (score 0):

Let $2a = (m+1) \theta$ and $2b = (m-1) \theta$ to obtain
$$f = \frac{\sin(a) \, \cos^{2}(b)}{\sin(b)} + \frac{\sin(b) \, \cos^{2}(a)}{\sin(a)}.$$
Now, consider the following:
\begin{align}
f &= \frac{1}{\sin(a) \, \sin(b)} \, \left(\sin^{2}(a) \, \cos^{2}(b) + \sin^{2}(b) \, \cos^{2}(a) \right) 
\end{align}
Using $2 \sin^{2} x = 1 - \cos(2 x)$ and $2 \cos^{2} x = 1 + \cos(2 x)$, then
\begin{align}
f &= \frac{1}{\sin(a) \, \sin(b)} \, \left(\sin^{2}(a) \, \cos^{2}(b) + \sin^{2}(b) \, \cos^{2}(a) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4 \sin(a) \sin(b)} \, ( (1-\cos(2a))(1+\cos(2b)) + (1-\cos(2b))(1+\cos(2a)) ) \\
&= \frac{1 - \cos(2a) \cos(2b)}{2 \, \sin(a) \sin(b)} \\
&= \frac{2 - \cos2(a-b) - \cos2(a+b)}{4 \, \sin(a) \sin(b)} \\
&= \frac{\sin^{2}(a-b) + \sin^{2}(a+b)}{2 \, \sin(a) \sin(b)} 
\end{align}

This can be seen in the form
$$f = \frac{\sin^{2}(m \theta) + \sin^{2}\theta}{\cos\theta - \cos(m \theta)}.$$

It becomes evident from $\sin(a) \, \sin(b)$ that there are problems (asymptotes) at 
$$\theta \in \left\{ \frac{2 n \pi}{m \pm 1} \right\} \hspace{5mm} n \geq 0. $$

Comment: not sure if i plotted the graph correctly, there seems to be discontinuity in the graph but your solution is continuous everywhere.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh  yes, I added incorrectly and obtained an incorrect result. Adding correctly produces a similar result that has been displayed.

Comment: Actually I started from your final result, you kind of derived back, what I want is to get rid of the denominator.